# Building Makefile using bazel

Tags: c++, git, makefile, bazel

I am trying to build Makefile of a submodule in a bazel project. I see that bazel does provide genrule to execute bash command. I am facing two issues currently -

**1. How to cd into a directory before executing command, something like -**

```
genrule(
    name = "hello-make",
    srcs = ["hello"] + glob(["hello/**"]),
    outs = ["hello/main"],
    cmd = "(cd $(location :hello) && make)",
)
```

**2. How do I update update submodule before executing genrule?**

Adding `cmd = "(git submodule init && git submodule update)"` gives `fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

Step to reproduce:

1. `git clone git@github.com:bazelbuild/examples.git`
2. `cd examples/ && git submodule add git@github.com:mucsi96/cpp-hello-world.git cpp-tutorial/stage1/main/hello`
3. `cd cpp-tutorial/stage1/ &&  bazel build //main:hello-world`

After this step I want to add a rule that allows me init, update and make the hello submodule.

Is there a better way to build `git@github.com:mucsi96/cpp-hello-world.git` than creating it as a submodule of `git clone git@github.com:bazelbuild/examples.git`?

The actual projects are more complex and creating a BUILD file for cpp-hello-world.git is not feasible.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/deepmind/lab/blob/master/glib.BUILD#L17-L19) is a semi-useful example -- something something `$(location ...)`?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I hope to fix this incrementally. I get `$(location) expression is not a declared prerequisite of this rule` on using `cd ./$(location hello)`

Comment: You need to refer to one of the declared names -- e.g. if you have `srcs = ["foo.txt"] + glob(["*.json]),`, then you could refer to `$(location :foo.txt)` etc. Maybe list your sources explicitly, or at least one of them (the `Makefile`)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of rolling your own `genrule` to build a (presumably C++) project that uses a `Makefile`, check out [`rules_foreign_cc`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc) instead. `rules_foreign_cc` is used by `envoy` and other various large C++ programs to build external CMake and Make based dependencies.

See the [`simple_make`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/tree/master/examples/simple_make) example. In it, you would first make a `filegroup` to collect all the sources and files related to the project to be built, including the `Makefile` itself:

```py
filegroup(
    name = "sources",
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    visibility = ["//simple_make:__subpackages__"],
)
```

Then, call `rules_foreign_cc`'s [`make` rule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/blob/16ddc00bd4e1b3daf3faee1605a168f5283326fa/tools/build_defs/make.bzl#L91), which also comes with other `make`-specific attributes like `prefix`, `make_env_vars`, and even a way to override the entire `make` command with `make_commands`. In this example, we're just using the `lib_source` and `static_libraries` attributes:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:make.bzl", "make")

make(
    name = "make_lib",
    lib_source = "//simple_make/code:sources",
    static_libraries = ["liba.a"],
)
```

Finally, run `bazel build //package/to:make_lib` to invoke the `make` rule.

> How do I update update submodule before executing genrule?

Try not to do this especially if it updates the sources of the project in-place. `genrules` and other rules should not modify the state of your sources during a build, but instead only build output files. Consider running a separate script to update submodules prior to the build.

Comment: Thanks, this is a very detailed and helpful answer! :) Say I do not have write access to the subproject I am trying to build. I the example, I can not have `BUILD` file in `code` dir and only parent dir. Is there a way to create filegroup in the `simple_make/BUILD` file, instead of `simple_make/code/BUILD`?

Comment: You can have the BUILD file in the parent dir - no worries. The alternative is to create a `new_local_repository` on that subproject, and apply your own `BUILD` file on it as though you're "writing" into the subproject, but I'd recommend to just write a BUILD file in the parent directory. You can learn more here: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/workspace.html#new_local_repository

Comment: followed up in a stackpost instead - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211438/output-external-name-repo-lib-lib-so-was-not-created-using-bazel-make

Comment: Another followup regarding [linking this so to cc_library rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58329033/how-to-link-a-library-build-using-make-rule-in-bazel)