# output 'external/name/x/lib/lib.so' was not created using bazel make

Tags: c++, makefile, bazel

I was trying to follow the example provided by [Building Makefile using bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035752/building-makefile-using-bazel)
 post to build an external package in envoy. In the WORKSPACE file I added the following:

```
new_git_repository(
    name = "name",
    remote = "remote.git",
    build_file = "//foo/bazel/external:x.BUILD",
)
```

And foo/bazel/external/x.BUILD has the following contents:

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:make.bzl", "make")

filegroup(
  name = "m_srcs",
  srcs = glob(["code/**"]),
)

make(
  name = "foo_bar",
  make_commands = ["make lib"],
  lib_source = ":m_srcs",
  shared_libraries = ["lib.so"],
)
```

and I set the visibility in foo/bazel/BUILD as `package(default_visibility = ["//visibility:public"])`

On executing `bazel build -s @name//:foo_bar`, I get the error that `external/name/x/lib/lib.so` was not created.

I checked the `bazel-bin/external/name/x/logs/GNUMake.log` and make completes successfully. I see that `BUILD_TMPDIR` directory has created lib.so. I think it should have been copied to EXT_BUILD_DEPS/lib, but I am not sure why it was not copied. Would appreciate any tips to debug the error.

Comment: Could you file an issue on https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/issues?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/issues/325

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited make command to manually copy the lib to expected folder - `make_commands = ["make libs; cp lib.so $INSTALLDIR/lib/lib.so"]`

Comment: How does the make rule evaluate $INSTALLDIR? I'm trying to use $INSTALLDIR in a custom rule, and it's evaluating to nothing.