# How to link a library build using make rule in bazel

Tags: c++, linker, bazel

I have built a lib.so using [make rule in bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58035752/building-makefile-using-bazel). How do I link this external lib.so to a regular cc_library rule. I tried adding it in deps, but the guide suggests that deps can have cc_library or objc_library targets.

Also, do I need to pass any specific linking options, and how can I read more about them?

Answer (score 2):

In the BUILD file, create a `cc_library` target that imports the built `lib.so` for other `cc_library` targets to depend on:

```py
cc_library(
    name = "lib",
    srcs = ["lib.so"],
    linkopts = ["...", "..."],
)
```

See the [documentation](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cpp-use-cases.html#adding-dependencies-on-precompiled-libraries) on C++ use cases for more information.

Comment: "..." denotes a placeholder for possible linking options? Is there any documentation explaining them?

Comment: Also, this gives `missing input file '@name//:lib.so'`

Comment: Yes, https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/c-cpp.html#cc_library.linkopts - the options are the exact flags you would pass to the linker, like `-ldl` or `-lm`.

Comment: Where is `lib.so` in `@name`? Is it in the top level package? Or is it created in a nested directory? If it's the latter, try `@name//:path/to/dir/lib.so`.

Comment: lib.so is built as part of make rule. It is not in the top level directory, but even with the suggestion i get the error `ERROR: missing input file '@name//:code/lib.so'`. I also tried adding a deps rule, but that did not help either.

Comment: The `missing input file` error means that the file label is incorrect. You should be able to get the actual file label of the built `lib.so` using `bazel query //path/to/package:*` (`:*` shows all file labels in a package).

Comment: The bazel offical document on using external library is basicaly a joke: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/cpp-use-cases.html#adding-dependencies-on-precompiled-libraries, it is not clear on how the library is linked, and the header file is included,  are there any samples on actually using an external library, from a specific path?